# Remove words before specific word in a list of list

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp

I have the following code to extract text from pdf. However, I need to remove all the words at the beginning of each file, specifically all the words before the word "Information" (just the first one).
I need to remove them and keep the rest of the file. All the text extracted must be stored at the end in a list of list as you can see in the code.
Here two sample PDFs that can be used a test.

```
pdf=[] #creating an empty list
for k in range(1,90):
    # open the pdf file
    output_string = StringIO()
    with open("G:/File (%s).pdf"%(k), 'rb') as in_file:
        parser = PDFParser(in_file)
        doc = PDFDocument(parser)
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = output_string.getvalue()
    text = text.split('\n')
    pdf.append(text)
    print(pdf[:])
```

PDFs are here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wmH98caKNe-dg4YrjxBSHj5bAd7bc93Z?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try :

```
text = output_string.getvalue()
text = text.split('\n')

indexes = [len(text)]

# finding Information word
information_index = text.index("Information")
if information_index != -1 :
    indexes.append(information_index)

# finding a second word 
blabla_index = text.index("Blabla")
if blabla_index != -1 :
    indexes.append(blabla_index)

# removing every word before Information or Blabla or ..., the first found
index = min(indexes)
text = text[index:]

pdf.append(text)
print(pdf[:])
```

Let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: Ok thank you. What if I would like to look for more than one word? Such as "Information or Info" ? I have tried information_index = text.index("Information" | "Info") but It doesn't work

Comment: I've edited the answer with a proposition to find several words.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen it. The problem is with what you mention " only works if you know that Information and Blabla are present in the text!" I can't be 100% sure because there are hundreds of PDFs files...

Comment: I keep getting the error of word not found...but i do have that secondo word...

Comment: oh, I didn't see that you were splitting on '\n'. Can you try replace text.split('\n') by text.split(" ") and let me know if it s better?

Comment: Arf, can you try to debug it on your side? It shouldn't be difficult. I cannot run on your pdfs right now.